# Find out the owner of a DBus service name

Tags: d-bus, notifications, freedesktop

I can't find a way to find what program implements the `org.freedesktop.Notifications` service. Is it possible to ask DBus to tell me what program provides it?

The reason for asking this question is quite banal: I found a new desktop notifications daemon I'd like to use, but it won't start and instead complains with this message

> Name Lost. Is Another notification daemon running?

However, I am unable to determine what program *is* holding the name. I already uninstalled every other notification daemon, restarted X server, and even rebooted the machine.

However, when I run this command:

```
dbus-send --session --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus --type=method_call \
--print-reply /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
```

`string "org.freedesktop.Notifications"` is present in the output, so *something* is holding the name, and I can't start my desired daemon.

Comment: I don't know of a way to get this information generically, but in this case the particular service you're asking about is usually provided by a daemon bundled with your desktop environment (Cinnamon, XFCE4, and MATE all do it this way), and it's usually somewhat difficult to get the desktop to use a different notification daemon if it comes with one bundled.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Thanks. I'm running AwesomeWM which does not bundle notifications daemon (I'm not actually sure about it, I'll investigate, thanks for the clue).

Comment: I think AwesomeWM provides the service itself internally actually (at least, on Gentoo and Debian it appears to be recognized as a notification provider).  If not, the most likely possibility is 'notify-osd', as that's the most widely used desktop-agnostic notification daemon out there.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn You've pointed me in the right direction! It was enough to comment out require("naughty") in Awesome's config, restart, and I was able to launch the daemon I wanted.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm actually still kind of curious myself if somebody out there knows of a way to trace a service name in DBus back to a process.  I bet there is something to do so, but a cursory look at the documentation isn't revealing anything for me either.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn I dont know how it does it, but `d-feet` found a pid. See my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The d-bus debug utility [d-feet](https://github.com/GNOME/d-feet) which is available as a package in many systems seems to be able to find the process id and command providing a service. For example, I ran it on a *Fedora 23 xfce4 X11 systemd* platform and selected `Session Bus` and entered the service name `org.freedesktop.Notifications`. It introspected the service, activating it, and showed the pid and `/usr/lib64/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd` command:

[image: before activation]

[image: after activation]

Answer (score 17):

You can get the caller `PID` via [`org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionUnixProcessID`](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#bus-messages-get-connection-unix-process-id):

```
qdbus  org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktop/DBus \
org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionUnixProcessID org.freedesktop.Notifications
```

```
737
```

so there's your `PID`.
If you prefer `dbus-send` (as `qdbus` is KDE specific) then:

```
dbus-send --session --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus / \
org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionUnixProcessID string:org.freedesktop.Notifications
```

```
uint32 737
```

If you prefer `gdbus` (which is GNOME specific) then:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.freedesktop.DBus --object-path / --method \
org.freedesktop.DBus.GetConnectionUnixProcessID org.freedesktop.Notifications
```

```
(uint32 737,)
```

---

On more recent `systemd` setups you could also use `busctl`:

```
busctl --user call org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktop/DBus  \
org.freedesktop.DBus GetConnectionUnixProcessID s org.freedesktop.Notifications
```

```
u 737
```